# Disabling special characters in ExtJS numberfield

Tags: extjs, validation, extjs3

I have a form in ExtJS in which I would like to put a field that can only take numbers as input. I would also like to disable other special characters (in particular, the % sign) since it seems that these special characters are considered as valid input no matter what restrictions are put on the field (basechars, regex, maskRe).

What is the best way to disable the special characters?

EDIT: Sorry for not being clear. I am already using a numberfield, and it does block all letters of the alphabet, but allows some special characters such as %, &, #, etc.

What I've tried:

```
numfield1 = new Ext.form.NumberField({
            fieldLabel: 'numfield1',
            name: 'numfield1',
            baseChars: "0123456789"
        });


numfield2 = new Ext.form.NumberField({
            fieldLabel: 'numfield2',
            name: 'numfield2',
            regex: /^[0-9]*/
        });

numfield3 = new Ext.form.NumberField({
            fieldLabel: 'numfield3',
            name: 'numfield3',
            maskRe: /[0-9]/
        });
```

All of these still allow special characters, and I would like the field to take numeric characters ONLY, and disallow all other special characters.

UPDATE: I've found that it works exactly as I expect it to on firefox, but the problem persists in chrome and safari. Does anyone have an idea of what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 3.4 there is the [NumberField](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.NumberField) which should enable you to prevent keystrokes other than numbers to enter data into your field.

To use it:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    defaultType: 'textfield',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Price',
        name: 'price',
        allowBlank: false,
        minValue: 0 //prevents negative numbers        
    }],

...

});
```